# Datatable - Change row data from html to plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datatable

The rails application is using the datatable to populate the data which is received from the remote system ( using ajax call) . the things were working fine till the remote system was sending plain text. But now the system is sending the response data as html. Because of that the whole page formating is disturbed. How to display the html returned as it is in the datatable row? The code is as below. The html returned from remote system is displayed in `message` field.

```
var logs = window.location.pathname + '/logs.json';
  var logTable = $("table").DataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sSearch": "Search"
    },
    "paging": false,
    "dom" : 't',
    "order": [[0, "desc"]],
    "ajax": {
     "url": logs,
     'dataSrc': function ( json ) {
       return json;
     }
   },
   "drawCallback": function(){
    refreshProgressBar();
  },
  columns: [
  {data : "created_at"},
  {data : "level"},
  {data : "message"},
  ],
  });
```

Comment: Can you update your question with the example HTML stored in the database? Also, have you tried calling `<%= raw @object.html_column %>`?

Comment: @MrShemek Added code. The html is very long. But you can consider any valid html page.

Comment: Okay, in that case, can you try using `raw` in the view (as mentioned in my first comment)?

Comment: @MrShemek where exactly in above code?

Comment: if you cannot revert it back as plaintext and it only return full html page consider to use nokogiri and scrap the html byurself

Comment: Which column is returning html data ?

Comment: @RocKhalil Message column is returning html data

Comment: @AnupamK please check this anwser: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41278951/2039726

Comment: @AnupamK can you post at least ONE response ? I think you need to update your API to return the `message` without the html tags unless you really need them.

Comment: @MrShemek, I will try that answer. and will check if this is exactly required.

Comment: @RocKhalil, Someone else implemented the API which can not be changed by me.